# Implementing Push notifications using parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to create a push notification using Parse on Android. After testing it I get this error. Any idea what to do? 
I tried the emulator and it works there, but it doesn't work on my device(Galaxy S3).

Got error when trying to register for GCM push

```
java.lang.Exception: GCM registration error: INVALID_SENDER
        at com.parse.GcmRegistrar$Request.finish(GcmRegistrar.java:325)
        at      com.parse.GcmRegistrar$Request.onReceiveResponseIntent(GcmRegistrar.java:315)
         at   com.parse.GcmRegistrar.handleRegistrationIntent(GcmRegistrar.java:202)
         at com.parse.PushService.onHandleGcmIntent(PushService.java:531)
         at com.parse.PushService.access$000(PushService.java:112)
         at com.parse.PushService$7.run(PushService.java:516)
         at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Can you post your code? It would help everyone.

Comment: so far its just the manifest code after following the instructions from parse.com

Answer (score 0):

Try add this on your Parse Java method:

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
```

I think I had the same error when I tried using Parse Push.

Comment: thanks, for helping but it turned out that i had to include the Project_ID from google api in the manifest, but now the notification is sent but it wont appear on my device. Any ideas?

Comment: Try turning your Wi-Fi off, then sending the push whilst you are on mobile data.